# How to get the file copy speed using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, file, stream, socket.io

I created a simple webpage using NodeJS and Socket.IO. The server needs to copy some files from a remote server to local server. I want to show this progress on the webpage, especially I want to show the file copying speed and give an estimated time. How can I do this using NodeJS?

Comment: If you're already using Socket.IO, is there any reason you don't send the relevant progress info from the server to the client over its connected socket?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I want to know how to get the copying file speed data. If I have the data, I can send it to webpage using Socket.IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your relevant code, we can only offer a generic answer.

To calculate the copying file speed, you start with two initial pieces of information which you must store for future reference during the operation:

1. The current system time (`startTime`).
2. The total amount of data to be copied (`totalBytes`).

Then, at any point while you are copying, you can get the current system time and the amount of data copied so far and create some calculations:

```
var elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
var portionComplete = bytesCopiedSoFar / totalBytes;
var percentComplete = portionComplete * 100;
var estimatedTotalTime = (elapsedTime / bytesCopiedSoFar) * totalBytes;
var estimatedTimeRemaining = estimatedTotalTime - elapsedTime;
```

Comment: @user2878435 - Corrected a couple of the formulas.